# Why Pandas cause ZeroDivisionError when read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I use `Pandas 0.17.1`.

When I run this code, I got ZeroDivisionError message. 
But when I read other csv file (the same content), it is working. Why?

Python:

```
import pandas as pd

def main():
    input_raw_data = pd.read_csv('wtf_table.csv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error message:

```
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

csv content

```
EQP ID,Unit Name,Data Source,Start Time,End Time,Event State,Duration (s),Event Name
QE,1,E, 2016/3/16 07:00, 2016/3/16 07:01,PROCESS,115.135,RECIPESTART
QE,1,E, 2016/3/16 07:00, 2016/3/16 07:01,PROCESS,0.823,RECIPEEND
QE,1,E, 2016/3/16 07:01, 2016/3/16 07:02,TRANSFER,16.924,PROCESSEND
```

Comment: Post your data or reproducible sample data or a link to your actual csv we can't generate your erroneous data from errors

Comment: As it stands your code cannot possibly load your csv correctly because your csv is not comma separated, you need to explain what the column names actually are and how this data is delimited

Comment: Works fine for me, although I just did the `input_raw_data` line by itself without all the wrapping.  If you want to do it the way you did, need to have the function return something -- e.g. `return pd.read_csv()`.  But I have no idea what the zero division error is, you must be doing other things also???

Answer (score 0):

It should add `encoding='utf-16'` to avoid unknown error

```
input_raw_data = pd.read_csv('wtf_table.csv',encoding='utf-16')
```